# Infinite recursion reference with JPA OneToMany, ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: java, jpa, recursion

I made some domains below.

```
@Entity
public class Conference {

    ...

    @OneToMany(
        targetEntity = ProgramDate.class,
        mappedBy = "conference",
        cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
     )
     @JsonBackReference
     private List<ProgramDate> programDateList;
}

@Entity
public class Program {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "program_date_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private ProgramDate date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class ProgramDate {

    ...

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Program.class,
            mappedBy = "date",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Program> programList;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "conference_id")
    private Conference conference;
}

@Entity
public class Room {

        ...

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Program.class,
            mappedBy = "room",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Program> programList;
}
```

And I made freemarker like below code.

```
     <#list conference.programDateList as date>
        ...
     </#list>
```

I meet a problem that is infinite recursion reference with JPA OneToMany, ManyToOne Relationship. I try to add `@JsonBackReference`, but it only resolved about the json recursive problem.

[image]

Comment: Where is the infinite recursion issue with JPA?  As JPA has object identity, it will not process an entity multiple times in bidirectional relationships, and allows for lazy fetching to help reduce bringing in a huge object graph when intending to read in only a single root entity.  I assume your issue is with serializing your object model, and if you are using the JsonBackReference annotation, it is this serialization causing you issues.  See http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion which shows using JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference

Comment: @Chris, It is occurred when I use loop Program Date in Conference like above picture. The day is recursive. I try to use JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference, but It still has recursion problem like above picture.

Comment: Again, that recursion doesn't appear to have anything to do with JPA, and JsonBackReference is not a JPA annotation.  How did your JsonBackReference annotation resolve the Json recursion problem - what was the problem?  Where is this problem manifesting itself, when you read data?  Check the data before you serialize it, as i really doubt there is an issue with your model's interaction with JPA other then serialization triggering lazy relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you include Room & Programdate in Conference, then in Program add a Conference along a Room & a Programdate which should already be contained in Conference ? Then in ProgramDate you have another reference to... conference and a list of program...

Basically you shouldn't try to "hack" out of these loops with some fancy annotations, but you should work on your data model. While Conference looks ok, Program could be a list of conferences only, and a Programdate should be... a date.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I try to edit my code. I remove Room and Program in Conference. Also I remove Conference in Room and Program. So, I resolve Program recursion. But, ProgramDate still has recursion problem like a new picture. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use json ignore annotation :

```
@OneToMany(
        targetEntity = Program.class,
        mappedBy = "date",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Program> programList;
```